# django + tailwind : tailwind not working in deployment environment on a ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, django, npm, tailwind-css

I have build a website in development environment using django and tailwind. I pushed the project to github and then cloned inside of a ec2 instance. The deployment worked fine (website running) besides the fact that tailwind won't work. Please forgive me if my question is dumb, it is my first project using tailwind.

I have made sure that node.js version and npm version are the same on my local environment and on my ubuntu server but I am still getting the issue.

From the django-tailwind documentation https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html , getting tailwind to deployment was the following command.

```
python manage.py tailwind build
```

doing that on my production server outputs the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.2.0
```

that is strange because

1. I installed it and still won't find it:

```
which semver
/usr/local/bin/semver
```

and 2. It was needed and not even there in development environment.

here is what tailwind.config.js look like:

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        /**
         * HTML. Paths to Django template files that will contain Tailwind CS>
         */

        /*  Templates within theme app (<tailwind_app_name>/templates), e.g. >
        '../templates/**/*.html',

        /* 
         * Main templates directory of the project (BASE_DIR/templates).
         * Adjust the following line to match your project structure.
         */
        '../../templates/**/*.html',
        
        /* 
         * Templates in other django apps (BASE_DIR/<any_app_name>/templates).
         * Adjust the following line to match your project structure.
         */
        '../../**/templates/**/*.html',

        /**
         * JS: If you use Tailwind CSS in JavaScript, uncomment the following>
         * patterns match your project structure.
         */
        /* JS 1: Ignore any JavaScript in node_modules folder. */
        // '!../../**/node_modules',
        /* JS 2: Process all JavaScript files in the project. */
        // '../../**/*.js',

        /**
         * Python: If you use Tailwind CSS classes in Python, uncomment the f>
         * and make sure the pattern below matches your project structure.
         */
        // '../../**/*.py'
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        /**
         * '@tailwindcss/forms' is the forms plugin that provides a minimal s>
         * for forms. If you don't like it or have own styling for forms,
         * comment the line below to disable '@tailwindcss/forms'.
         */
        require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
        require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
        require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
        require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    ],

        
}
```

and here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "theme2",
  "version": "3.1.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "npm run build:clean && npm run build:tailwind",
    "build:clean": "rimraf ../static/css/dist",
    "build:tailwind": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss --postcss -i>
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/sty>
    "tailwindcss": "node ./node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/cli.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.3.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^6.0.3",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

I am super confused about what to do about this error or about what to do to make things work, not much can be found online so any advice would be welcome!!

UPDATE:

I have tried uninstalling and re installing Semver at various locations including the root of the project, next to Node js in the server and nothing does the trick.

I have also tried to push the node modules in the github repo and then pull from the server. I verified in my local computer, and there is no semver package, neither in the project or anywhere. The same error still persist and I am still unable to find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you have installed semver , then why it is not relfected in TailwindCSS. I suggest you to install it again in the production environment .

Comment: I have it installed. I am going to uninstall and do it again to see whats up